# Image Fusion Using wavelet transform in python

Tags: python, image-processing, wavelet-transform

How to fuse 2 images using wavelet transform. There are several methods available such as Principal Component Analysis, High Pass Filtering, IHS, etc. I want to know how to fuse using Wavelet transform. I know the theory behind and want to know how to implement it in Python.

Here is the link of Image Fusion Based on Wavelet transform https://www.slideshare.net/paliwalumed/wavelet-based-image-fusion-33185100

Comment: You say you know the theory so please add an explanation how to do the fusion in theory and than maybe people that don't know the theory could help you with the implementation.

Comment: @AmitayNachmani  https://www.slideshare.net/paliwalumed/wavelet-based-image-fusion-33185100

Comment: Can you please post two image you want to fuse

Comment: @AmitayNachmani  will the process be specific to Images which we use?

Comment: No, but if i will try to use your images and give you the result it will be more easy to know if you got what you looked for.

Answer (score 10):

First you need to download PyWavelet 
https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Second run the following code on your images:

```
import pywt
import cv2
import numpy as np

# This function does the coefficient fusing according to the fusion method
def fuseCoeff(cooef1, cooef2, method):

    if (method == 'mean'):
        cooef = (cooef1 + cooef2) / 2
    elif (method == 'min'):
        cooef = np.minimum(cooef1,cooef2)
    elif (method == 'max'):
        cooef = np.maximum(cooef1,cooef2)
    else:
        cooef = []

    return cooef


# Params
FUSION_METHOD = 'mean' # Can be 'min' || 'max || anything you choose according theory

# Read the two image
I1 = cv2.imread('i1.bmp',0)
I2 = cv2.imread('i2.jpg',0)

# We need to have both images the same size
I2 = cv2.resize(I2,I1.shape) # I do this just because i used two random images

## Fusion algo

# First: Do wavelet transform on each image
wavelet = 'db1'
cooef1 = pywt.wavedec2(I1[:,:], wavelet)
cooef2 = pywt.wavedec2(I2[:,:], wavelet)

# Second: for each level in both image do the fusion according to the desire option
fusedCooef = []
for i in range(len(cooef1)-1):

    # The first values in each decomposition is the apprximation values of the top level
    if(i == 0):

        fusedCooef.append(fuseCoeff(cooef1[0],cooef2[0],FUSION_METHOD))

    else:

        # For the rest of the levels we have tupels with 3 coeeficents
        c1 = fuseCoeff(cooef1[i][0],cooef2[i][0],FUSION_METHOD)
        c2 = fuseCoeff(cooef1[i][1], cooef2[i][1], FUSION_METHOD)
        c3 = fuseCoeff(cooef1[i][2], cooef2[i][2], FUSION_METHOD)

        fusedCooef.append((c1,c2,c3))

# Third: After we fused the cooefficent we nned to transfor back to get the image
fusedImage = pywt.waverec2(fusedCooef, wavelet)

# Forth: normmalize values to be in uint8
fusedImage = np.multiply(np.divide(fusedImage - np.min(fusedImage),(np.max(fusedImage) - np.min(fusedImage))),255)
fusedImage = fusedImage.astype(np.uint8)

# Fith: Show image
cv2.imshow("win",fusedImage)
```

The fusedImage is the resulted fusion of I1 and I2

Comment: in the same link i posted there is a link to there tutorials

Comment: @Rakshith Gb Yes. It is not language dependent. Find a wavelet library for C++ and use opencv for dealing with the images and you can rewrite it in c++

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is the was way to perform Image Fusion without losing the color information (RGB) channels? Eg: By reading the image as `I1 = cv2.imread('i1.bmp')
I2 = cv2.imread('i2.jpg')`

Comment: @Jithin I am not sure but i think you can just do it for each channel separately and then combine the channels back to get the rgb.